# CLLocation DistanceFrom performance implications

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm developing an iOS application where I need to track the distance walked by the user real-time and alter data accordingly.

Essentially what I'm doing is, as soon as the user makes a move, I check the distance between the original and current positions and react accordingly (using CLLocation's DistanceFrom method).

**Are there performance implications of using DistanceFrom repeatedly that I should be prematurely worried about?**

Edit: Forgot to mention, I'm using Xamarin.iOS (aka MonoTouch)

Comment: I did use something similar in my apps and so far I had no performance issues. Unfortunately I don't have any measurement or anything like this, but the app was running successfully. So IMHO you are concerned about something that has really little to none impact on the app performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling that CLLocation's DistanceFrom method just uses the [haversine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) method under the hood. So wont have a huge effect on performance.

I have used this before and not noticed much in the way of performance. Bit more [info](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue wont likely be the distance computation, but the retrieval of the geo location information in the first place.

Apple has a handy guide on things you should keep in mind to reduce battery usage:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10